# Front end clunk and resistance on 2003 Honda Civic

Tags: honda, noise, civic, frontend

We have a 2003 Honda Civic that was parked outside uncovered for 2-3 years. I got it up and running but when driving there is now a "clunk" from the front end and the car slows down a bit with the clunk. It seems to happen whenever the wheel does one rotation. It seems to come from the driver's side but that might just be my perception. I put the car up on jack stands and did a bit of an inspection but didn't really see anything out of ordinary except that there was a little bit of rust on the brake rotors. When I manually turn the wheel there is a bit of resistance at the same point every time. It resists right at the point where the pads were covering the rotor for those years parked. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your caliper. It could be stuck. The piston should push in smoothly using a small plate and c-clamp.

Check slides and slide pins for movement.

Check brake hose for damage.

Check rotor runout for warpage caused by all or one of above.

If you can't do any of this a shop can. The brake pads are not relieving enough and one or more of these things are probably causing it from setting so long.